# How do I know if my image exists on the server? (PHP)

Tags: php, image, verification

I have a simple code that checks whether a file exists or not in the server.

```
 <?php
 $filename = 'www.testserver/upload/productimg/IN.ZL.6L_sml.jpg';

 if (file_exists($filename)) {
      echo "The file $filename exists";
 } else {
      echo "The file $filename does not exist";
 }
 ?>
```

**Problem:** My local webserver says that the file does not exist even though when I copy paste the url in the browser, I can see the image.

How can I make the condition say that the file does not really exist?

Comment: You need to construct the local path in relation to the webservers `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, not use an URL-like string.

Comment: `www.testserver/...` is not a valid **file path**. Either you're talking about a URL on a remote server, in which case you need to use `http://www...`, or you mean a *local* file on the same server, in which case you need to use the *local* file path like `/usr/local/var/...`.

Comment: is `www`actually part of your path ? Is it a folder ? If not you probably shouldn't use it within `file_exists` function, but use the local path instead...

Comment: `filename` should probably be a local path (i.e. only `/upload/...`. Otherwise, it should be an absolute remote path, including a protocol, e.g. `http://`

Comment: OP, please [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for real path of image you can try:

```
<?php
 $filename = 'www.testserver/upload/productimg/IN.ZL.6L_sml.jpg';
 $testImage  = @file_get_contents($filename);

 if ($testImage != NULL) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
 } else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be, making a request and checking for the response headers:

```
   <?php
    $headers = get_headers('http://www.example.com/file.jpg');

    if($headers[0]=='HTTP/1.0 200 OK'){
       return true; // file exists
    }else{
       return false; // file doesn't exists
    }
    ?>
```

**Code live example:**
http://codepad.viper-7.com/qfnvme

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$filename = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/upload/productimg/IN.ZL.6L_sml.jpg";
```

for testing the file.